# When using dd(), the session is not being extended

Tags: laravel, laravel-10

I set the session lifetime to the minimum of 1 minute for testing purposes.
In one of the controllers in the `index()` method, I simply `dd()` some data.

I noticed that even if I constantly refresh the page in that minute, it won't extend the session, as if the request never gets to the part that extends the session, and when a minute passes, the user is logged out (even though I refreshed the page non-stop)

Why? I thought that until it reaches the controller method it also passes through the part where it extends the session and the user should continue to be logged in even when using `dd()`.

(When I remove the `dd()` and keep refreshing the page, the user is not logged out)

Comment: the `dd`, dump and die,  is not allowing the session middleware to do its clean up (the way out of the middleware stack), which includes saving the session data

Comment: Maybe you want `dump` so you just _dump_ info and not stop execution?

Comment: Thanks, got it. Do you guys maybe have the place in the source code where it actually saving it and can link to it? Just curious